# CREATE TABLE T1 ... LIKE ... creating table with cluster key if source table defined with cluster key in SNowflake

Tags: cluster-analysis, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

It is mentioned in documents that the snowflake does not propagate cluster key from the source table if the table is created with 'CREATE TABLE .... LIKE.....';

From Documentation :

•   An existing Clustering key is not propagated when a table is created using CREATE TABLE … LIKE.

```
CREATE
    OR replace TABLE 
CUST_1GB_CL ***cluster BY (C_CUSTKEY)*** (
    C_CUSTKEY NUMBER(38, 0) NOT NULL
    ,C_NAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
    ,C_ADDRESS VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
    ,C_NATIONKEY NUMBER(38, 0) NOT NULL
    ,C_PHONE VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
    ,C_ACCTBAL NUMBER(12, 2) NOT NULL
    ,C_MKTSEGMENT VARCHAR(10)
    ,C_COMMENT VARCHAR(117)
    ); 


create table CUST_1GB_CL3 like CUST_1GB_CL;


GET_DDL('TABLE', 'CUST_1GB_CL3')

CREATE
    OR replace TABLE 
CUST_1GB_CL3 ***cluster BY (C_CUSTKEY)*** (
    C_CUSTKEY NUMBER(38, 0) NOT NULL
    ,C_NAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
    ,C_ADDRESS VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
    ,C_NATIONKEY NUMBER(38, 0) NOT NULL
    ,C_PHONE VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
    ,C_ACCTBAL NUMBER(12, 2) NOT NULL
    ,C_MKTSEGMENT VARCHAR(10)
    ,C_COMMENT VARCHAR(117)
    );
```

Comment: Actually, the docs say:

"CREATE TABLE … LIKE:

If the source table has clustering keys, then the new table has clustering keys. By default, Automatic Clustering is not suspended for the new table – even if Automatic Clustering was suspended for the source table."

I'm facing the same problem, how to workaround this: create a table from another, only metadata, but WITHOUT copying the cluster key or even the primary keys. I know I can drop the cluster key, but the whole point is to avoid that being created along table creation from source table in the 1st place, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is strange. I think following up with Snowflake on this is best course of action.

If you want you can drop the clustering key in your new table as follows: 
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS CUST_1GB_CL3 DROP CLUSTERING KEY;